# $\frac{1}{(1+s^{2}) (1+t^{2})}$ real analytic in $\mathbb R^{2}$ but not real-entire; why?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

A complex valued function $F,$ defined on  an open set  $E$ in the plane $\mathbb R^{2}$, is said to be real-analytic in $E$ if to every point $(s_{0}, t_{0})$ in there corresponds an expansion with complex coefficients
$$F(s, t)= \sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty} a_{nm}(s-s_{0})^{m} (t-t_{0})^{n},$$ 
which converges absolutely for all $(s,t)$ in some neighbourhood of $(s_{0}, t_{0}).$

If $F$ is defined in the whole plane $\mathbb R^{2}$ by a series
$$F(s, t)= \sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty} a_{nm}s^{m} t^{n},$$
which converges absolutely for every $(s,t),$ then we call $F$ real-entire.

> **My Question is**: How to show

$$f(s,t) = \frac{1}{(1+s^{2}) (1+t^{2})}, (s,t \in \mathbb R)$$

is real- analytic in the whole plane $\mathbb R^{2}$ but not real-entire.

Thanks,

Comment: the double series is just the product of the series in $s$ and the series in $t,$ both with radius of convergence $1.$

Comment: @WJ; thanks, sorry I could not follow you; would you please tell me, how  does it help ?

Comment: If you multiply functions you multiply their power series. Your function is $1/(1+s^2)$ multiplied by $1/(1+t^2).$ Just carefully write out your terms $a_{nm}$ for, say, $0 \leq m,n \leq 3$ and see what happens.

Comment: @JW; $f(s)= \frac{1}{1+s^{2}} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m} s^{2m}; (|s|<1) $, and $\frac{1}{1+t^{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} t^{2n}, (|t|<1);$ but from this I don't see why at any point of $\mathbb R^{2}$ has neighbourhood so $f(s,t)$ has series expansion, which converges absolutely ?  would you explain me bit more ? thanks a lot;

Answer (score 1):

If $(s,t)\mapsto f(s,t)$ is real-entire in $\mathbb R^2$, then plugging  $t=0$ into the power series we get a real-entire function $s\mapsto f(s,0)$.

In this case $f(s,0)=\dfrac{1}{1+s^2} $, which is not real-entire.  The radius of convergence of the power series at $0$ is $1$.

---

To show your function is real-analytic, use the fact that  $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ is real-analytic. Which can itself be proved in various ways, e.g. by general theorem that $f/g$ is real-analytic on the set $\{g\ne 0\}$ provided $f,g$ are real analytic.